# I'm at a [loss] for words

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loss)

No excerpt or wiki. 298 questions.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Describes a general "loss" in most cases. Lost settings, values, [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667255/leave-minimal-tip), etc.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Too generic a concept to have a question just tagged [loss]

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

In most cases, no. [This is the top upvoted question in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158616/lost-code-lines-when-notepad-crashed) and the tag is meaningless there.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. It depends on what was lost.

---

I think this tag is competing with the more specific [loss-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loss-function) tag in some cases (most notably [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow))

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was also used to refer to a machine learning model's loss function.

Comment: Is the tag harmful in any way?

Comment: @E_net4 As in [this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loss-function)?

Comment: @rene Good point. I added something about that. I think there's some confusing usage

Comment: @rene It would certainly be no [loss] to the site if we got rid of it - seems like a thoroughly useless tag to me.

Comment: "No excerpt or wiki" - honestly, all it would need is "| || || |_".

Comment: @TamásSengel of all the places where I would have expected to see this, SO was the last one. Well played sir.

Comment: Thanks to this post, I just lost the game.

Comment: @TamásSengel Sorry, I didn't get the joke. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @neverMind9 [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/8o2hr6/what_does_mean/), I guess.

Answer (score 17):

After looking at the tag, I've seen [loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loss) is mostly being used for a TensorFlow method called [tf.losses](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses). This tag having 298 questions, has 106 questions about [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow), 98 questions tagged with [keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras) (a method in [keras, an optimization score function](https://keras.io/losses/) and sure could use its own tag).

I suggest we edit out questions which are using this tag to indicate loss or other variations of the sort and add a wiki to this tag, so it could be used properly.

Judging by the tag's ambiguous name, It should also be renamed to something which *actually* tells about the question, it is being used in. Or better, should be merged to [loss-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loss-function). Peculiarly, that tag is also wiki plus excerpt-less

Comment: Note: loss (AKA cost) is a technology-agnostic concept in machine learning with the purpose of defining a function we want to minimize. TensorFlow has named that module `losses` because of that. It is not specific to TensorFlow, and I don't believe people are using the tag because of that specific tf module.

Comment: @E_net4 Yes. What I said is that, it is being used and has questions. So it should be merged, renamed to [loss-function] or something more relevant. I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Renaming it to `loss-function` seems to make sense to me, as long as it's also removed from any questions about any other kind of losses.  The name `loss` is way too generic a tag for only ML purposes.

Comment: @alkanen turns out we have a `loss-function` tag and it is being used. We should merge it into that tag

Comment: @weegee ah, yes, of course.